# Deblurring an image through matrix operations in MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, matrix, matlab-figure, blur

I want to de-blur an image. The image is `1100x1100` and the colormap is `256x3`. To blur an image, one would perform matrix multiplication according to the following equation: Y = XH', where X is the original image. To de-blur the image, one would do X = Y/H'. Hence, I ran the following code.

```
L = 1100; 
N = 850;
c = [ones(1,N)/N zeros(1,L-N)];
r = [1/N zeros(1,L-1)];
H = toeplitz(c,r);
pic1 = pic/H'; //pic is defined as the original image: 1100 x 1100
image(dePic);
```

However, when I run this code, I just get a heat map and not the original image. Where am I going wrong? Am I doing the math incorrectly in MATLAB? `N=850` is the optimal value for `N`. This I have confirmed. But just for sanity check, I tried altering `N` and didn't have much luck.

I also tried the following code. But it just converted the heat map to black and white and didn't have much affect.

```
L = 1100;
N = 850;
c = [ones(1,N)/N zeros(1,L-N)];
r = [1/N zeros(1,L-1)];
H = toeplitz(c,r);
pic1 = pic/H';
colormap(map); //map is 256x3
image(dePic);
axis image;
```

Comment: Just in case, have you noticed that the "image processing toolbox" include some built-in deblurring function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a complete fool. when I call `image()`, I'm passing in the wrong argument.
Here's the updated code that works beautifully.

```
L = 1100;
N = 850;
c = [ones(1,N) zeros(1,L-N)];
r = [1 zeros(1,L-1)];
H = toeplitz(c,r);
H = H/N;
pic1 = pic*inv(H');
colormap(map);
image(pic1);
axis image;
```

This works.